# Remove specific elements from array Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Currently I have an array like this:

```
var list = new Array([
        {id: 0, content: "zero", group: 1},
        {id: 1, content: "one", group: 2},
        {id: 2, content: "two", group: 1},
        {id: 3, content: "three", group: 1},
        {id: 4, content: "four", group: 3},
    ]);
```

How can I remove the entries where group == 1 using javascript or Jquery?

Comment: That is a strange way to create an array, you end up with an array containing the array containing the objects.

Comment: It's a very... Java... way to create an array.

Comment: You might take a look at [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Note: you have to iterate the list using a loop but care for a correct counter when removin elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the array in the following way:

```
var list = [
  {id: 0, content: "zero", group: 1},
  {id: 1, content: "one", group: 2},
  {id: 2, content: "two", group: 1},
  {id: 3, content: "three", group: 1},
  {id: 4, content: "four", group: 3},
];
```

otherwise you will end up as an array containing another array. After that you can filter the array on the following way:

```
var filtered = list.filter(function(item) {
  return item.group !== 1
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `new Array` - your code creates an array with one element, which is itself an array with five elements. You should just use an Array literal:

```
var list = [
    {id: 0, content: "zero", group: 1},
    {id: 1, content: "one", group: 2},
    {id: 2, content: "two", group: 1},
    {id: 3, content: "three", group: 1},
    {id: 4, content: "four", group: 3},
]
```

Once you've done that, you can use `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
var filtered = list.filter(function(item) {
  return item.group !== 1;
})
```

If you do mean to build a 2D array you could still use filter:

```
var filtered = [list[0].filter(function(item) {
  return item.group !== 1;
})]
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript:

```
   list =list.filter(function(item){
     return item.group!=1
   })
```